# Is there a shortcut to proxy-resolve/reject a promise to an Angular $q deferred?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Given an unresolved deferred (`dfd`), and a then-able promise (`promise`), which may or may not be deferred, is there a way to 'proxy' the promise into the deferred?

The semantics should be as so:

```
promise.then(dfd.resolve, dfd.reject);
```

[The $q documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/service/$q) only mentions handling of rejected promises (and furthermore, only promises rejected in a certain way):

> defered.resolve(value) – resolves the derived promise with the value. If the value is a rejection constructed via $q.reject, the promise will be rejected instead.

This makes it unclear if `dfd.resolve(promise)` is valid/supported. Also, I cannot use `$q.when` (which does take a then-able) because the promise of the defered has already been returned.

The Angular version is 1.2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `deferred.resolve` takes a promise.

**deferred.resolve(value)**

Calling resolve with a pending promise causes promise to wait on the passed promise, becoming fulfilled with its fulfillment value or rejected with its rejection reason (or staying pending forever, if the passed promise does).

Calling resolve with a rejected promise causes promise to be rejected with the passed promise's rejection reason.

Calling resolve with a fulfilled promise causes promise to be fulfilled with the passed promise's fulfillment value.

Calling resolve with a non-promise value causes promise to be fulfilled with that value.

> From the [Q API Reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)

**To answer another part of your question:**

""This makes it unclear if dfd.resolve(promise) is valid/supported. Also, I cannot use $q.when (which does take a then-able) because the promise of the defered has already been returned.""

The promise created by `deferred.promise` can be given to more that one recipient. Each recipient can call the `.then` method on that promise. The promise can only be resolved once (either to a value or an error). But the container can be read by more that one consumer.

Think of a promise as a container for a value which you can get **in the future** by the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` methods. You can visit the container more than once but its contents are immutable when it resolves.

**Deprecation of the `.success` and `.error` methods in the `$http` service**

The AngularJS team in their new found wisdom have decided to deprecate the `.success` and `.error` methods. Those methods were buggy and I say **good riddance**.

For more information on the deprecation (or should I say failure) of the `.success` and `.error` methods visit the latest [AngularJS $http Service API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

We should avoid the `.success` and `.error` methods and learn to use the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` from now on.

The `$q` service reference cited by the OP is dated. For the latest version, visit [AngularJS $q Service API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

**UPDATE for Legacy AngularJS v1.2**

I did some [spelunking in the AngularJS Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L716). The legacy `$http` service creates a `$q` promise [(L750)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L750) and subsequently attaches the buggy `.success` method [(L769)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L769) and the buggy `.error` method [(L776)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L776).

What this means is that people stuck with using the older version of AngularJS can start migrating to the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` methods.

An example with two consumers of the same `$http` promise.

```
//Producer
var httpPromise = $http.get(url);

//Consumer #1
httpPromise.then (function (response) {
                vm1.data = response.data;
        }) .catch (function (err) {
                //check for error
        });

//Consumer #2
httpPromise.then (function (response) {
                vm2.data = response.data;
        }) .catch (function (err) {
                //check for error
        });
```

Notice that the `.then` method returns data differently than the `.success` method.

Also both consumers should check for errors.

So even users of legacy AngularJS can start writing `.success` and `.error` free code.

Comment: Remember `$q` (from Angular) and `Q` (by mage Kris Kowal) are different, albeit with confusingly similar names, and the devils are in the details of the particular Promise implementation.

Comment: AngularJS takes its $q service from Kris Kowal's source. So this API reference is from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Sadly, we 'must' support IE8, hence the dated Angular version specified (and documentation link used).

Comment: @user2864740 See the update for legacy AngularJS 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Any time you resolve a promise to another promise (whether by `resolve()` or by returning from a callback), it will implicitly wait for that other promise.

In fact, it is impossible to make a promise actually resolve to another promise instance (without waiting).

Comment: This is a good answer in a nutshell. I especially found the last statement very useful.