# GET JSONP data from php file in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Recently, I began to study Angular. So much I do not know. I'm trying to get json data from a php file to use within an Angular controller. But the data from php file does not exceed.

**controllers.js:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$resource', '$http',
function($scope, $resource,$http) {
    $http.get('/xbmc.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

**xbmc.php:**

```
    <?
include('sys/inc/config.inc.php');
include(SMARTY_DIR.'Smarty.class.php');
include(BASE_DIR .'sys/inc/classes.inc.php');
include(BASE_DIR .'sys/inc/init.inc.php');
include(BASE_DIR .'xbmcApi.php');
$jsonData = new xbmcApi($_GET['action']);
/**
if (MEGAKINO_LOGED)
{
**/
    $json = $jsonData->getResult();
/**
}
else 
    $json = array('authStatus' => '0');
**/     
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**index.html:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4" style="margin-top: 0.5%;" ng-repeat="item in data.items">
                <div class="image" style="margin-bottom: 1%">
                    <a data-ng-href="#!/seasons/serie/{{item.id}}">
                        <img data-ng-src="/files/series/thumb-{{item.id}}.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <a data-ng-href="#!/seasons/serie/{{item.id}}">
                        <b>{{item}}</b>
                        <u>Рейтинг: {{item.rate}}</u>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is `$json` stores the correct output ?

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` inside the promise function and tell us what you see.

Comment: did you test your php with browser address bar, does it work ? And do you have any error when yo use angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code tells that your json will be build if a `$_GET['action']` param is passed:

```
$jsonData = new xbmcApi($_GET['action']);
```

Yet, you are not passing any data as a query string from your angular controller. Try something like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$resource', '$http',
function($scope, $resource,$http) {
    $http({
        url: '/xbmc.php', 
        method: "GET",
        params: {action: 'some_action'}
     }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

AS @CharlieH said, check for errors on your console:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$resource', '$http',
function($scope, $resource,$http) {
    $http.get('/xbmc.php')
        .then(function(response) {
             $scope.data = response.data;
    })
        .catch (function(error) {
             //check for errors here
             console.log(error);
             throw error;                   
    });
}]);
```

Also the `.success` method has been deprecated. We should all be migrating to using `.then` and `.catch`. For more information on that see: [Deprecation of the .success and .error methods in the $http service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860223/5535245)