# Extracting the specific header message from the $http response headers

Tags: .net, angularjs, http

I am(data,status,headers,config,statusText) using $http.post() to make server calls in an application. The server code is in .net. For a specific use case, when a process fails, the server returns a Business Exception along with a message.

Now I can see the message getting printed in Chrome's console in red color, along with a 404 code. Also I can see the message in Fiddler's header section at top, as "HTTP/1.1 404 Message goes here". But I don't get how to extract that message out of response headers.

I tried the following,

```
$http.get(requestURL).success(
                function (data,status,headers,config,statusText) {
                    //deferred.resolve(data);
                    console.log("In service",data,status,headers,config,statusText);
                }).error(
                function (data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    //deferred.reject(data);
                    console.log(data, status, headers, config, statusText);
                });
```

The headers is printed in console as a function, "function anonymous(name)" I need help extracting something out of it, (if at all possible). The statusText is printed as undefined. I really need help here, as I need to display the sent message to users.

If it matters: The message is being send in "reasonPhrase" property from server

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated. You should be using `.then`.

Full details are available on this page - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

In your example, you should use something like this:

```
$http.get(requestUrl).then(function (response) {
  // success handling
  console.log(response.headers());
}, function (response) {
  // error handling
  console.log(response.headers());
});
```

`response.headers` is a function. When you call it (`var headers = response.headers();`) then it will return an object containing the headers from the HTTP response.

As per the details on the page linked above, within the response object you have access to the following:

- data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of angularjs you are using but the "traditional" `success` and `error` callback have been deprecated for a while.

Please consider the new approach with `.then(...)` see here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

But to answer your question: 
The `headers` parameter in the callback function represent a getter, so you need to call it: `headers()`. You can also apply a parameter (a specific header) there.

Comment: Add that `.then` works with old Angular see [Update for Legacy AngularJS v1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33860223/5535245)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't know about that. So there is no reason to stay with the old syntax @Saurabh - you will also find more docs about the new approach.