# Use Wrapped promise or plain promise

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

I read this article here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service
It says it is popular pattern to use wrapped promise, but Angular's official Doc here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http says "The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error", which way should I take? It seems I will have to use then().

Can any one shed some light? Thanks

Comment: Avoid the `.success` and `.error` methods. They don't chain well and are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:** Don't wrap `$http` promises.

In the [article you cite](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service#Summary), the guy writes:

> Personally I’ve resigned myself to simply forwarding the $http generated Promises and using .success() and .error() at the cost of a little bit of inconsistency. At this point I have to know that this particular call in my service returns an $http promise, and that I need to call the .success() and .error() functions on it rather than .then() to handle the callbacks rather. But I still prefer that to wrapping my services with extra Promises. Regardless of where you push this behavior, somewhere in the stack you end up having this inconsistenty where the difference between $http promises and stock Promises shows up – so I might as well push it up into the application layer and save some senseless coding to hide an implementation detail.

This is nonsense. The `$http` service has always returned `$q` promises. The `.then` and `.catch` methods have always been available. (Not well documented, but available.)

Here is something, I wrote for another question.

**Deprecation of the `.success` and `.error` methods in the `$http` service**

The AngularJS team in their new found wisdom have decided to deprecate the `.success` and `.error` methods. Those methods were buggy and I say **good riddance**.

For more information on the deprecation (or should I say failure) of the `.success` and `.error` methods visit the latest [AngularJS $http Service API Docs -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

We should avoid the `.success` and `.error` methods and learn to use the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` from now on.

**Legacy AngularJS v1.2**

I did some [spelunking in the AngularJS Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L716). The legacy `$http` service creates a `$q` promise [(L750)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L750) and subsequently attaches the buggy `.success` method [(L769)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L769) and the buggy `.error` method [(L776)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L776).

What this means is that people stuck with using the older version of AngularJS can migrate to the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` methods.

-- [Is there a shortcut to proxy-resolve/reject a promise to an Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859863/is-there-a-shortcut-to-proxy-resolve-reject-a-promise-to-an-angular-q-deferred/33860223#33860223)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification